# Difference in placement of negation symbol?

Tags: logic, notation, quantifiers

Let's say we had a dictionary Axy = x agrees with y; b = Bob. Consider the following:

1. $\neg \forall x Axb$
2. $\forall x \neg Axb$

They both seem to translate to "There is no one that agrees with Bob". Would there any difference between the placement of the negation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second statement $\forall x\neg Axb$ means "for every person, it is not true that this person agrees with Bob", in other words,

> everybody disagrees with Bob.

$\forall xAxb$ means "everybody agrees with Bob", so the first statement $\neg\forall xAxb$ means "it is not true that everybody agrees with Bob", that is,

> somebody disagrees with Bob.

These statements are not the same.

Comment: Would first statement would be equivalent to ∃x¬Axb and ¬∃xAxb?

Comment: The first statement would be equivalent to the first formula in your comment, but not equivalent to the second formula.

Answer (score 1):

They're not the same, ther first one says: "Is not the case which all individues agree with Bob." The second one is: "For all individues, is not the case whic they agree with Bob."

Answer (score 0):

$\neg \forall x~Axb$ : *not everyone does agree with Bob*.   There *may be* some who do agree.

$\forall x~\neg Axb$ : *everyone does* not *agree with Bob*.   There is *certainly* no one who does agree.

The sentences are distinct.